# CKEditor Text fonts size gets changed on Copy of text from outlook [IE 11 ONLY]

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a strange issue where in the fonts of the text gets changed while copying the text from outlook (desktop) to CKEditor.

**All the fonts gets bigger than what is in the source.**

This issue happens **only in IE 11** and in Chrome it preserves the fonts fine.
I have tried several events to catch the text and do some formatting but this screws up the fonts in Chrome.

Any solution/suggestion welcome.

Comment: can you please check this documentation : 
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_copyformatting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content from MS Office is usually extra filtered by [Paste From Word](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/pastefromword) plugin. By design this plugin should work for Word only ([more info here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_pastefromword.html)), but sometimes when browser has better Clipboard API support it might work for other MS Office products (like Outlook). I suspect that in this case in Chrome data are filtered using mentioned plugin and are not filtered in IE11. This might be a reason of different content in editor for both cases.

To catch pasteddata and modify it before inserting to editor's content, you should use [paste event](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-paste). Example how to use it you can find below or under link: https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/mqJPde?editors=1011

You can modify inserted data according to your needs. Actually Paste from Word is one big filter which detects data pasted from MS Word and applying filter or modifies excess things.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );

editor.on( 'paste', function( evt ) {
  console.log( evt.data.dataValue ); // There is no additional paragraph yet.
  evt.data.dataValue = '<p>Additional Paragraph</p>' + evt.data.dataValue; // Modify data pasted to editor.
} )
```

Comment: Thanks that did help me in getting bit close to my desired result